# Orange light on charger but MacBook Air won' t turn on

Tags: macbook-pro

First my MBA was working great, but suddenly my charger wouldn't work anymore (no light when plugged in.)

Then the MBA, not charged, entered a dead state. I bought a new charger after 2 months and when plugged in, the light turns orange but the MBA won't turn on. I left it charging all night but light still orange. After I reset the SMC, the charger light goes green for 2 seconds, but nothing happens. I have an A1466 MBA from 2013.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: sounds like your Battery is dead

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you mentioned when performing SMC is normal. When performed the charging indicator will flash green to indicate the SMC reset was recognized. This generally indicates the MagSafe board is communicating correctly with the logic board.

An internal component such as the logic board, battery, or PCIe cards may have failed. That may need to be diagnosed and replaced